# ChunkedWriteHandler did not handle 100 Continue response properly to send all the chunks

Tags: java, netty, nio

I have used the netty 4.0.9 (or 12) HttpUploadClient way to send large (>8K) post request.
However, after the first chunk sent to the server, the server sent back "100 continue".
The ChunkedWriteHandler did not handle the "100 Continue" to send the remaining chunk.
Instead, the 100 Continue was passed upstream the top handler which can't handle.
How can the ChunkedWriteHandler be modified to handle the "100 Continue" response to
resume sending the remaining chunk to finish the large post request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is fixed in 4.0.15 for the AbstractMemoryHttpData.java getChunk() function.

The exception was IllegalReferenceCountException in AbstractByteBuf.java.

However, in the ChunkedWriteHandler.java doFlush(), there is catch(final Throwable t),
which may prevent any future other exception to propagate unless explicitly check it.

Answer (score 0):

`ChunkedWriteHandler` is a protocol agnostic handler, so you should not add anything specific to HTTP.

Instead, you could update your last handler in the pipeline so that it understands 100-Continue message.  Before writing any chunks, you'd better wait for 100-Continue response first.

Alternatively, you could just remove the `Expect: 100-continue` header from your request, then the HTTP server will not send such a response.

Comment: Trustin: Thanks for the response.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The request did not have the "Expect: 100-Continue", the server sent the "100-Continue" anyway which I have no control. The second method was also tried with the following:    channel.writeAndFlush(request); // Header parts only.  Then in the handler after the 100-Continue received.    channel.writeAndFlush(requestEncoder); // Send the request body parts.   However, only the first chunk was sent, not the second part. So any idea how to debug this?

Comment: Hmm, if you can write a simple HTTP client and server code that demontrates the problem without contacting any public server, I'd be happy to investigate further.  Please feel free to file an issue.